# Laravel and React CORS error only on certain routes

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

```
\\Routes
Route::view('/{path?}', 'app');
Route::post("users/signup", "App\Http\Controllers\Users@signup");
Route::post("users/email/verify", "App\Http\Controllers\EmailVerificationController@verify");
Route::get("users/email/resend", "App\Http\Controllers\EmailVerificationController@resend");
```

```
\\Verify email once the user clicks on their email
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\VerifyEmail;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailVerificationController extends Controller
{
   public function verify( Request $request){
       $user = User::where($request->input("token") ,"verification_token");

       if($user){
           $user->markEmailAsVerified();
           $user->email_verified_at = now();
           return response()->json(["msg" => "Email has been verified"]);
       } 
   }

   public static function sendVerificationEmail($email,$username,$verificationToken){
       $userInfo = [
           "username" => $username,
           "verification_token" => $verificationToken,
       ];
       Mail::to($email)->send(new VerifyEmail($userInfo));
   }
}
```

```
\\Frontend for the VerifyEmail Page
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import {instance} from "../axios"

const VerifyEmail = () =>
{
    let {token} = useParams();
    useEffect( () =>
    {
        instance.post( `users/email/verify`, {
           token
        } ).then((response) => console.log(response)
       ).catch((err) => console.log(err.response))
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            Hello
        </div>
    )
}

export default VerifyEmail
```

I'm trying to verify users' emails, so when a user signs up, an email is sent with a token and when they click on the link of the email, it takes them to the VerifyEmail component in the frontend. Then this component makes a request to the backend with the token to check the database for this token and mark this email as verified, but I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/social-api/public/users/email/verify' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost/social-api/public/users/email/verify net::ERR_FAILED
```

If I change the post request and I try to do a simple get request,then I get this error in the response.

```
"message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\social-api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 43,
```

The issue was in the config cors file, changed it from this

```
'paths' => ['social-api/public/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

to this

```
'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Comment: Did you enable CORS? Works good in other routes?

Comment: Yes it works fine, when I post my data on the SignUp controller

Comment: you said when you change the post request to get request you get that error response, that one I suppose happens because you are not changin the request type also on the routes file on the Laravel side, but that alos wouldn't help with the cors response; you need to enable or allow the origin from which you are trying to make the requests on the api

Comment: No I did change the route on the backend as well,and when it's a get request it doesn't throw a cors error, it's just a 404 @RinorDreshaj

Answer (score 1):

there's a tiny, little itsby bitsy problem that you shoud take care of.

sometimes this little things can make you a lot of headache, searching,disappointing and so on ...

look for **trailing slash** at the end of your URL.

ex:

1. test.domain.com/api/user
2. test.domain.com/api/user/

second url is more likely to cause CORS error (believe me. take it serious)

**solution:**

1. you may watch out every single url to remove this trailing slash, OR ...
2. if you're using axios, just place request interceptors to modify your url before sending request:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  
    // ** removing trailing slash from end of url
    // ** this little slash (which seems its called trailing), causes CORS error
  
    config.url = config.url.replace(/\/$/, "");
    
    return config;
});
```

Comment: if you are using a javascript fetch how would you accommodate removing the training slash?

Comment: in js fetch, I don't think we have interceptors. just remove it with a simple function:
`url.endsWith('/') ? url.slice(0, -1) : url;`